# Is there a place to store luggage in/around the Golden Palace (Kinkaku-ji) in Kyoto?

Tags: luggage-storage, kyoto

For annoying reasons, it would make sense to visit the Golden Palace between checking out of one Kyoto hotel and checking into another. However both hotels are pretty far away from Kinkaku-ji.

Is there a place nearby that can hold bags for an hour or two while I visit the palace?

Comment: There's no luggage storage at the temple, but if you can tell us your hotels, we can probably suggest some place along the way.  Also, I presume leaving your bags at either hotel is not an option?

Comment: One is in the very far west/northwest, the other is near Shiyakushomae railway station.

Comment: "Very far west" = Arashiyama, or even further out?  Can you give us a place name?

Comment: Aren't there any coin lockers at the Kyoto station? Why wouldn't you just put your stuff there. That's what I would do. I did that for Osaka.

Comment: Usually hotels are kind to keep the luggage for some time while you are not yet checked in or already checked out. Lockers at Kyoto station are very limited and usually crowded, so there's little chance to use them.

Answer (score 3):

Ask hotel A to arrange for delivery to hotel B. The delivery industry here puts FedEX to shame, it will cost about $15 per bag and if not the same day will definitely be overnight. So take what you need for one day and let someone else haul your bags around.

This is a daily request for any hotel in Japan, they won't have any problems doing it for you.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to coin lockers, Kyoto station has a manned luggage counter.

The day I arrived in Kyoto, I'd used the coin lockers in Nara earlier in the day, and so was sort of aware of them being around.  Can confirm that a quick search online shows that they're at the bottom of the escalator from the normal (not Shinkansen) JR train central exit.

([Source on kyotovisitors.blogspot.com.au](http://kyotovisitors.blogspot.com.au/2009/04/kyoto-station.html))

You can then train to Kitaoji and take the 10-15 min bus ride up the hill to the Golden Palace.